# Accesing two threads in one button click function

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

This is not throwing me any error but after executing first thread it is not executing second thread. Am I doing anything wrong?

Below is my code:
My button click Function:

```
 private void ImportBothButtonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the currently selected manufacturer from the combo box
        var selected = comboBox.SelectedItem;

        // Do we have one?
        if (selected != null)
        {
            // Extract the combo record
            var val= (ComboBoxItem)selected;

            // Do we have one?
            if (val != null)
            {
                // yes
                // Make this on a seperate thread so that the UI continues to work
                Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
                {
                    button1.Enabled = false;
                    button2.Enabled = false;
                    button3.Enabled = false;
                    var thread = new Thread(DoFunction1);

                    thread.Start(val); 
                }));

                Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
                {
                    button1.Enabled = false;
                    button2.Enabled = false;
                    button3Enabled = false;
                    var thread = new Thread(DoFunction2);

                    thread.Start(val);
                }));

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: see this on how to execute both http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133642/c-sharp-execute-2-threads-simultaneously

Comment: @sam That is expecting void function in Thread call

Comment: Why the need of `Invoke(...)`? These threads will run parallel. It won't  wait until thread 1 is ready.

Comment: Actually...I think you have misunderstood what Windows.Invoke/Forms.Invoke actually does. In both cases, you are actually running code on the UI thread. Thus it is all going to be single threaded. However given you are changing UI elements you HAVE to use the UI thread. YOU CAN NOT DO MULTITHREADING.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those Actions will not do a thing. The actions are Invoked on the same thread you're currently on.

The threads are currently running parallel. If you want those threads to run in serial but not on the gui thread, you could do something like this:

**This is the NON-TASK version.**

```
// not allowed on a non-gui thread.
button1.Enabled = false;
button2.Enabled = false;
button3.Enabled = false;

new Thread(() =>
{
    DoFunction1();
    DoFunction2();

    // execute this on the gui thread. (winforms)
    this.Invoke(new Action( delegate
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = true;
    }));

}).Start();
```

If you want to run them parallel, but wait until they are done:

```
// not allowed on a non-gui thread.
button1.Enabled = false;
button2.Enabled = false;
button3.Enabled = false;

new Thread(() =>
{
    ManualResetEvent wait1 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    ManualResetEvent wait2 = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
        {
            DoFunction1();
            wait1.Set();
        });

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
        {
            DoFunction2();
            wait2.Set();
        });

    ManualResetEvent.WaitAll(new WaitHandle[] { wait1, wait2 });

    this.Invoke(new Action( delegate
        {
            // execute this on the gui thread. (winforms)
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = true;
            button3.Enabled = true;
        }));
}).Start();
```

But this can be more easy using tasks. *Task Parallelism (Task Parallel Library)* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Comment: I am getting cacnot convert lambda expression to type System.delegate because it is not a delegate type error

Answer (score 2):

Please clarify what is the exact problem you observe?

According to what you have currently stated, the problem lies in "the second thread is not run after the first thread".

So, let me answer to this.

Your code is almost OK. You have overlooked **one important thing**: your code "new thread / thread.start()" actually do start a new thread, and then **it does not wait** for that thread to execute nor complete.

lines:

```
new thread(f1).Start()
new thread(f2).Start()
```

will not "run F1 on thread1, then run F2 on thread2". Instead, they will "begin to run F1 on thread1 and immediately begin to run F2 on thread2".

To have the F2 executed only after F1 has fully finished, you must somehow 'chain' the two together:

- you can create simple "agenda" method and run it instead:

  ```
  private void doAllTasks()
  { 
      f1();
      f2();
  }

  new thread(doAllTasks).Start()
  ```
- you can try "chaining" them on the fly via lambdas, which effectively is the same as above:

  ```
  new thread(() => { f1(); f2(); ).Start()
  ```
- you can actually run them both immediatelly, but have the F2 **join [wait]** until the F1's thread ends

  ```
  var th1 = new thread(f1);
  var th2 = new thread(() => {th1.Join(); f2();} ) 

  th1.Start();
  th2.Start();
  // note that this code is NOT perfect, there's some error handling to do here, etc..
  ```

or, you can try some nice and pretty wrappers for all of that like the TPL framework, as seen in **Sheridan's answer**.

And of course you must be careful with touching UI elements from inside what those other new thread's are running. Sheridan's answer already covers it via TPL ways. Manually, you'd have to use Invoke/BeginInvoke to bounce the UI-related code back to UI thread. In your current code you already have it, but at that place, it is **not necessary**, since the _Click handler method obviously already runs in UI thread.

Therefore, your current example can be reduced to i.e.:

```
private void ImportBothButtonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selected = comboBox.SelectedItem;

    if (selected != null)
    {
        var val= (ComboBoxItem)selected;

        if (val != null)
        {
            // no Invoke needed, "button_click" handlers
            // are already on UI thread, so touching UI things is OK
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = false;

            // starting a new thread also does not need Invoke
            var thread = new Thread(DoAllFunctions);
            thread.Start(val); 
        }
    }
}

private void DoAllFunctions(object something)
{
    DoFunction1(something);
    DoFunction2(something);

    // button1.Enabled = true; - cannot do it here because they are UI
    // button2.Enabled = true; - and DoAll is run from other thread.
    // button3.Enabled = true; - you must bounce that back to UI thread.

    LetTheUIKnowJobsAreFinished(); // <- performed here
}

private void LetTheUIKnowJobsAreFinished()
{
    Invoke(new Action(()=>{
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = true;
    });
}
```

Also, as a final note, **please** go and look at the `BackgroundWorker` from System.ComponentModel. It has very nice set of events/callbacks that will make all the thread-crossing very easy.

(btw. let me say that again: this code is NOT usable. it is only a sketch. you will find typos, missing colons, missing try-catch-whatever etc!)

Comment: Thanks Very well explained.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like this?:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = false;
    button3.Enabled = false;
}), new CancellationToken(), TaskCreationOptions.None, 
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()).
ContinueWith(new Action(() => DoFunction1)).
ContinueWith(new Action(() =>
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = false;
    button3Enabled = false;
}), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()).
ContinueWith(new Action(() => DoFunction2));
```

Comment: -1 This will cause an exception due to the buttons being "owned" by the UI thread.

Comment: yep, now it is much better

Comment: Come on @Aron, is this a reason to -1 this answer? This idea can still be implemented with minor changes..

Comment: The original code before the correction has duplicated the exact same bug as the author tries to fight. So, -1 seemed quite ok. Now after the correction it is not relevant and I htin kshould be cancelled.