# How to receive data via serial port on background thread while main thread is continuously receiving on another serial port and updating winform?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, serial-port

I need to communicate with two devices via serially via USB to UART modules and update my winform. First one is running fine but I must be doing something wrong while receiving from second serialPort. I have made sure that on hardware side, data is being transmitted and received but I think my program is not being prompted when the data is received on second serialPort. Any help is appreciated.

The way it is supposed to work is this: When started, the program starts receiving from serialPort1 continuously and keeps updating the User Interface in real time. The second serial Port is only used when LStart Button is pressed(refer to the second thread code indicated within the code body). At that point, the program is supposed to send a predefined string and receive a response. The problem is that this program is never prompted by any response even though the USB-UART module confirms receiving something.
P.S. I am not from software background nor do I have considerable experience in c# so expect somethings that may be stupid on my part.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.Ports;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Globalization;


    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)

            serialPort1.Open();



        if (!serialPort2.IsOpen)                   
        {
            serialPort2.Open();
            richTextBox1.Text = "Port Opened";
        }                                          
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)

            serialPort1.Open();

    }





    private void Read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private string serialRx = string.Empty;
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, 
    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        serialRx += serialPort1.ReadExisting();                                              
    // Add new data to what we have
        string[] lines = serialRx.Split(new char[] { '$' }, 
    StringSplitOptions.None);        // Each line starts with a $ so, split 
    @ $

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)                                          
    // Not processing the last one yet. It might not be complete yet
        {
            if (lines[i].StartsWith("$ABC"))                                                
    // Checking if its the line we are looking for
            {
                 string[] values = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });                                       
    // Splitting @ "," and after this, do what ever we wanna do with these         
    splitted part(s)

                foreach (var value in values)
                  {

                     Invoke(new Action(() => """dataprocessing1"""

                  }
            }
        }
    }






    **/// <Second Thread Code is below>**

    private void LStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(StartMeasuring);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
        LRFStart.Enabled = false;
    }

    private delegate void DisplayCountDelegate(int i);
    private delegate void EnableButtonDelegate();
    private delegate void ClearBoxDelegate();
    private delegate void WritePort2Delegate();
    private delegate void DisplayReceivedDelegate(string mess);

    private void StartMeasuring()
    {   
        LStart.Invoke(new WritePort2Delegate(WriteonSerial2));     
    }

    private void WriteonSerial2()
    {
        string Actionmeasurement = "ABCDEFDS>";
        serialPort2.Write(Actionmeasurement);
    }

    private void EnableButton()
    {
        LStart.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void ClearBox()
    {
        richTextBox1.Clear();
    }

    private void DisplayReading(string mess)
    {    
        string Reading = mess;
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Reading);
        richTextBox1.Invoke(new ClearBoxDelegate(ClearBox));
        LStart.Invoke(new EnableButtonDelegate(EnableButton));
        Reading = string.Empty;
    }

    private string receivedThisTime = string.Empty;
    private void serialPort2_DataReceived(object sender, 
    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
     receivedThisTime += serialPort2.ReadExisting();
     richTextBox1.Invoke(new DisplayReceivedDelegate(DisplayReading), 
        receivedThisTime);   
       }   
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have never worked with 2 serial ports at the same time. But I think you'll need to get some information about `Threads`.

You have to create 2 threads ( 1 for `serialPort1` and another for `serialPort2`).

You can't do it only with one `thread`.

Content about `Threads`: [Thread.Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[Example of Running 2 Threads at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133642/c-sharp-execute-2-threads-simultaneously)

Comment: If I start a simple 0-9 counter her instead of serial port 2, both processes work perfectly. That makes me think its not problem of threading, it is how I am using the serialPort2.